# Amount of ways to assign unique rooms to distinct guests

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are $n$ guests staying at a motel. When checking in they are each assigned a unique room in the motel. There initially are a total of $m$ rooms available. How many different ways are there to assign room numbers to each of the guests?

We have $m$ distinct rooms and $n$ distinct guests.

Say $n=3$ and $m=2$, then we can assign room numbers in the following way:

**Room 1, Room 2**

Guest 1, Guest 2

Guest 1, Guest 3

Guest 2, Guest 1

Guest 2, Guest 3

Guest 3, Guest 1

Guest 3, Guest 2

Would it be correct to assume that the amount of different ways there are to assign room numbers to each of the guests is equal to $\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$ in the case that each guest has to check in one by one?

Comment: Your formula does not appear to make sense if $m>n$.  Is that case excluded?

Comment: Hi lulu, thank you for your reply. There are no particular restrictions on the value that $n$ and $m$ can take on. I did not think of permutations not being an option when $m > n$. Is there a way to correct for this in the equation I provided for permutations?

Comment: I suggest treating the cases $m<n$ and $m>n$ separately.  The case $m=n$ is simply $n!$  The two other cases are very similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming only one person per room, where each person gets a room, then you must have $m \geq n.$ Then, the correct formula is

$$\frac{m!}{(m-n)!}.$$

That is, there are $m$ choices for the first guest, then $(m-1)$ choices for the 2nd guest, ..., then $(m+1-n)$ choices for the $n$-th guest.

If $n > m$, then the first thing to do is decide which $m$ people will get a room.  This can be done in $~\binom{n}{m}~$ ways.  Then, it is as if the $n$ people have been reduced to $m$ people, so there are then $m!$ ways of assigning the people to the rooms.

So, when $n > m$, the computation is

$$\binom{n}{m} \times m! = \frac{n!}{(n-m)!}.$$

This can be intuited as follows:

Instead of assigning rooms to people, you are assigning people to rooms.  Then, there are $n$ choices for which person is assigned Room-1, then $(n-1)$ choices for which person is assigned Room-2, ..., then $(n+1-m)$ choices for which person gets assigned Room-m.